# dotnet restore in Github Actions gives 401 unauthorized

Tags: c#, nuget, github-actions, .net-6.0, github-package-registry

a NET6 project on GitHub cannot be dotnet-restored in GitHub Actions. `dotnet restore` works fine locally. Looking at the [Action logs](https://github.com/mdddev/meh/runs/6226647275?check_suite_focus=true), it seems GH looks for Microsoft dependencies in *my* GitHub Packages Repo. `System.Linq` is MS-stuff.

```
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/mdddev/download/system.linq/index.json'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
/home/runner/.dotnet/sdk/6.0.202/NuGet.targets(130,5): warning : Your request could not be authenticated by the GitHub Packages service. Please ensure your access token is valid and has the appropriate scopes configured. [/home/runner/work/meh/meh/meh.sln]
```

Further below in the pipeline there is a step to publish the result to the GitHub Packages registry, however in the project itself I am only using public NuGet references. I am not sure why GH Actions looks for the .NET stuff in my registry. I even have the public NuGet feed configured in my `nuget.config`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <clear />
        <add key="nuget" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
        <add key="github" value="https://nuget.pkg.github.com/mdddev/index.json" />
    </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Does anyone know what's the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using GitHub packages here, you have to authenticate yourself.

for more info -> https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-nuget-registry#authenticating-with-a-personal-access-token

Comment: I thought I had. Still, the project itself only references nugget not GH packages. https://github.com/mdddev/meh/blob/7ac550a7814b628d7f857dfd77dbe9fd9856d350/.github/workflows/ci.yaml#L14

Comment: if you are using nuget as package source than why you have added github in package sources?

Comment: @baouss https://github.com/manishtiwari25/meh/runs/6228040731?check_suite_focus=true  please have a look here..

Comment: just remove nuget.config, if you are not using github packages.

Comment: I am including GH Packages in the nuget.config because later in the GH Action there is a `dotnet pack` and ``dotnet publish`, which puts the nupkg file in this  GH Package registry. Again, dotnet restore works without a problem when run locally with the same configuration, this leads me to believe, that this should not be the root cause of the problem. Hower I might be mistaken

Comment: so the root cause is https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-nuget-registry#authenticating-with-a-personal-access-token, you have to add personal access token in nuget.config, it is working fine locally because it is using your personal github creds.

Comment: @baouss if you still wants the  config file than remove the github things, https://github.com/manishtiwari25/meh/runs/6228383736?check_suite_focus=true

Comment: Ok I got it [working](https://github.com/mdddev/meh/actions/runs/2245509656), thanks @Manish for your help. As proposed I deleted the nuget.config alltogether. Because then the dotnet publish failed with an unknown source error, [I added a step in the action adding it on the fly](https://github.com/mdddev/meh/blob/4489c4be5f4ec67c5d02cb47781c2332e6d6dddc/.github/workflows/ci.yaml#L41).

Comment: @baouss if my answer helped, cloud you please mark this as answer?  it will help other people.

Comment: @Manish Link only answers are often closed. How would you authenticate yourself? Are there other options? 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `GITHUB_TOKEN` for automatic authentication you should know that you must explicitly give view permissions PER PACKAGE, PER REPOSITORY! So if you have a large volume of internal libraries you want to pull in to your solution you have to go in to each one and allow each package to be used by your new solution.

This takes a surprisingly large number of clicks in a large code base. I certainly hope they improve this process by granting permissions on an organization level for shared libraries, a bulk select, or command line way of granting permissions en masse.

[Ensuring workflow access to your package](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/learn-github-packages/configuring-a-packages-access-control-and-visibility#ensuring-workflow-access-to-your-package)