# Issue with dotnet restore on GitHub Actions when accessing GitHub Packages

Tags: .net, authentication, nuget, github-actions, github-packages

I am facing an issue with a GitHub Actions workflow that involves dotnet restore. The repository is hosted on GitHub, and I'm trying to restore NuGet packages from a GitHub Packages source.

Here's a snippet of my GitHub Actions workflow YAML:

```yaml
name: Build .NET 7 + Pack + Push NuGet

on:
  workflow_dispatch: # Allow running the workflow manually from the GitHub UI
  push:
    branches:
      - "main" # Run the workflow when pushing to the main branch
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - "main" # Run the workflow for all pull requests
  release:
    types:
      - published # Run the workflow when a new GitHub release is published

env:
  DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE: 1
  DOTNET_NOLOGO: true
  NuGetDirectory: ${{ github.workspace }}/out

defaults:
  run:
    shell: pwsh

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      id-token: write
      packages: read

    steps:
      - uses: actions/labeler@v3
        with:
          repo-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
    
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0 # Get all history to allow automatic versioning using MinVer

      - name: Setup .NET
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: 7.0.x

      - name: Add GitHub NuGet Source
        id: add-nuget-source
        run: |
          dotnet nuget add source https://nuget.pkg.github.com/user/index.json -n github -u user -p ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} --store-password-in-clear-text
        continue-on-error: true

      - name: Restaurando Dependências
        run: dotnet restore
        #if: success() && steps.add-nuget-source.outputs.result == '0'

      - name: Build do Projeto
        run: dotnet build -c Release -o out
        
      #- name: Test
      #  run: dotnet test --no-build --verbosity normal

      # Publish the NuGet package as an artifact, so they can be used in the following jobs
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: nuget
          if-no-files-found: error
          retention-days: 7
          path: ${{ env.NuGetDirectory }}/*.nupkg

  run_test:
    name: Rodando os Testes Unitários
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [build]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Setup .NET
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      - name: Run tests
        run: dotnet test --configuration Release

  deploy:
    # Publish only when creating a GitHub Release
    # https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/releasing-projects-on-github/managing-releases-in-a-repository
    # You can update this logic if you want to manage releases differently
    # if: github.event_name == 'release'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [run_test]
    # Download the NuGet package created in the previous job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: nuget
          path: ${{ env.NuGetDirectory }}

      - name: Publicando os pacotes Nuget
        run: |
          cd out
          dotnet nuget push "*.nupkg" --api-key "${{ secrets.NUGET_APIKEY }}" --source "${{ secrets.NUGET_SERVER }}" --skip-duplicate
```

The issue occurs during the dotnet restore step with the following error:

> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.100/NuGet.targets(156,5): warning : Your request could not be authenticated by the GitHub Packages service. Please ensure your access token is valid and has the appropriate scopes configured.
> Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/user/download/package/index.json'.

Additional Information:

The NuGet packages are stored in a GitHub repository, and I have configured the workflow to use the GitHub token for authentication.
The issue seems to be related to authentication during the dotnet restore step.
I would appreciate any guidance on how to properly configure the GitHub Actions workflow to resolve this issue.
Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: "in a GitHub repository". If that repository belongs to another organisation, then your GITHUB_TOKEN won't suffice. Either transfer your repository to the same organization or follow the advice below (use a personal token that has been authorized with the org in question).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same exact error message and managed to solve it by updating the `ClearTextPassword` in the `packageSourceCredentials` for github in the nuget.config with an active token that has the `read:packages` permission.

```
<packageSourceCredentials>
    <github>
        <add key="Username" value="YourUser" />
        <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="{yourTokenWithPackageReadPermissions}" />
    </github>
</packageSourceCredentials>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a package references to the org vs a repo.

You can use the **nuget source add**, as you did, but use a generated user PAT and store it in your repo or org actions/secrets instead of using GITHUB_TOKEN.

Odd for me that **dotnet nuget push** can use an api-key parameter that accepts GITHUB_TOKEN but **dotnet restore** seems not to be able to that token.  Even with permissions: packages:read granted on the build steps does not work.

```
- name: Add Github Source
  run: dotnet nuget add source <https://your-package-source> --name <some-name>  --username ${{ github.actor }} --password ${{secrets.PACKAGE_REGISTRY_PAT}} --store-password-in-clear-text
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a solution to your problem here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78050829/8840033

> If you are using GITHUB_TOKEN for automatic authentication you should
> know that you must explicitly give view permissions PER PACKAGE, PER
> REPOSITORY! So if you have a large volume of internal libraries you
> want to pull in to your solution you have to go in to each one and
> allow each package to be used by your new solution.
>
> This takes a surprisingly large number of clicks in a large code base.
> I certainly hope they improve this process by granting permissions on
> an organization level for shared libraries, a bulk select, or command
> line way of granting permissions en masse.

[Ensuring workflow access to your package](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/learn-github-packages/configuring-a-packages-access-control-and-visibility#ensuring-workflow-access-to-your-package)

For example:
[image]

Alternatively, you can set your the visability of the package as internal:

[image]